# I'm using Zend gdata to open documents with hopes to read and write spreadsheet cells

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata-api, spreadsheet

I'm not good at programming and my trying to open one of my spreadsheet documents.
Below in the basic login im using, I then request a list all my spreadsheet, which is returned in $feed.

And now I'm worried I'm not on the right track with opening a document so I can read and write cells.

```
<?php

require_once '../library/Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
$user="username";
$pass="user password";

// login
$service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);

$spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);
$feed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();

print_r ($feed);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot which social network my id was with, and so I have Activ8ed a new. A bit like a cylon.

> I looked at the zend manual. I'm new
>   to php so accessing Objects like $feed
>   is still confusing. The Zend document
>   needs to make better usage of http to
>   expand the information present.
>
> ie. the quote from zend manual
>
> > "Given the spreadsheet key from the
> >      of a
> >     Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_SpreadsheetEntry
> >     object you've already retrieved, you
> >     can fetch a feed containing a list of
> >     worksheets associated with that
> >     spreadsheet."

$feed returns [Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_SpreadsheetEntry](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Gdata/Spreadsheets/Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_SpreadsheetEntry.html) object

Ok so I've learned to display the files available with the code below.

> foreach ($feed->entries as $entry) {
>     echo $entry->title->text .' '.
>     $entry->content->text . "\n"; }

I think I'm starting to get it, but not sure what I should be reading.

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Gdata/Spreadsheets/Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets.html
Is making more scene too. But it's missing links to http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ListingSpreadsheets which is the structure on $feed, well a pointer to a segment of one.

Trying more to Understanding how objects class's and functions are used in PHP.
reading  [Class variables, scope resolution operator and different versions of PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539677/class-variables-scope-resolution-operator-and-different-versions-of-php)

[Is this a reasonable way to handle getters/setters in a PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145/is-this-a-reasonable-way-to-handle-getters-setters-in-a-php-class)

Did I mention this, http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ListingSpreadsheets

http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/zend-framework-select-statement-and-where-clause-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  Are you using the information found http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html ?

Your code is getting a spreadsheet feed which lists all the available spreadsheets, which is an important step.  You'll want to follow the link above to get a list-based feed or a cell-based feed.

The documentation is pretty good I would recommend just reading through it all(yes it's long).

Comment: Thanks,  I also found this today. http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/02/03/Saving-a-PHPExcel-spreadsheet-to-Google-Documents.aspx  So just need some time to try it all out.