# Class variables, scope resolution operator and different versions of PHP

Tags: php, class-variables

I tried the following code in codepad.org:

```
class test { 
  const TEST = 'testing 123';
  function test () {
    $testing = 'TEST';
    echo self::$testing;
  }
} 
$class = new test;
```

And it returned with:

```
1
2 Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property:  test::$testing on line 6
```

I want to know whether referencing a class constant with a variable would work on my server at home which runs php 5.2.9 whereas codepad uses 5.2.5 .
What are changes in class variables with each version of PHP?

Answer (score 3):

> The Scope Resolution Operator (also
>   called Paamayim Nekudotayim) or in
>   simpler terms, the double colon, is a
>   token that allows access to static,
>   constant, and overridden members or
>   methods of a class.

The variable you define in the function test ($testing) is not a static or constant, therefore the scope resolution operator doesn't apply.

```
class test { 
  const TEST = 'testing 123';
  function test () {
    $testing = 'TEST';
    echo $testing;
  }
} 

$class = new test;
```

Or just access the constant outside the class:

```
test::TEST;
```

It should work on your server at home if used correctly. In regards to the OOP changes from PHP4 to PHP5, the [php documentation](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) may be useful. Although just off the top of my head, I would say that PHP5's main changes as they relate to class variables would be their visibility, static's and constants. All of which are covered on the documentation link provided.