# Why are public methods accessible at the class level

Tags: php

Consider this example,

```
class A {
        public function who() {
            echo 'The name of the class is ' . __CLASS__;
        }
    }
A::who();
```

Output: The name of the class is A

And this,

```
class A {
        public $vars=12;
    }
echo A::$vars;
```

Which results in the following error,

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property:
>   A::$var in G:\xampp\htdocs\Learn_PHP\PHP1\name_class.php:10 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   G:\xampp\htdocs\Learn_PHP\PHP1\name_class.php on line 10

What is happening? Why is a public method accessible via class?
And why is the same not happening with a property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class variables, scope resolution operator and different versions of PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539677/class-variables-scope-resolution-operator-and-different-versions-of-php)

Comment: To explain simply what the others are saying: You need to make an instance of your class, which is called an 'object'. Which is a core principle of OOP. If you want to be able to call a function without making an object of that class you can use a static function.

Comment: @Grenther That's not the point. Why does `who` **not** require an instance to be created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874376/php-what-if-i-call-a-static-method-in-non-static-way

Comment: @meagar I'm just explaining the concept of static functions

Comment: @Grenther But why does `who`, a **non static function**, operate on the class as though it were static?

Comment: @meagar because obviously the person asking the question doesn't understand the theory and should be explained what objects are and what static functions are. Thus explaining the essence of both sounds like a good way to help them progress.

Comment: As of PHP 5.6, [this feature is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php) which is a non-fatal error, whilst accessing the property is a fatal error.  Not that I think PHP is ever inconsistent.

Comment: @Grenther That doesn't answer anything. Twice now you've completely ignored my question. You haven't at all explained the evident contradictory behavior here. There is no reason to assume the OP "doesn't understand the theory" behind OOP, it's PHP's behavior that is surprising and non-conforming to typical OOP conventions here, and if anything your explanation only confuses things because it contradicts PHPs actual behaviour.

Comment: I don't think that proposed duplicate really answers this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the php.net page for Scope Resolution Operator:

> The Scope Resolution Operator (also called Paamayim Nekudotayim) or in simpler terms, the double colon, is a token that allows access to static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class.

Your function is a method, hence the use of `::` is ok. The variable however isn't static or a constant, nor is it an overridden property of a parent class. So the use of `::` won't work for it.

full page from docs: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 0):

To make the second example works as the first one just change it as follows

```
 class A {
        public static $vars=12;
    }
    echo A::$vars;
```

By adding Static to the attribute because you are calling it in a static way.

Actually PHP allows calling none static methods in a static way as of first example, but not for none static variable.

According to documentation this behavior will be changed in PHP 7

> Warning In PHP 7, calling non-static methods statically is deprecated,
>   and will generate an E_DEPRECATED warning. Support for calling
>   non-static methods statically may be removed in the future.

Please review this URL [Static keyword in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: You missed the point of the question. It's not about why `$vars` doesn't work, it's about why `who` **does** work.